# How can I publish many ROIs in a detection node?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I have simple object detection node that reads frames from the usb camera and performs face detection. I would like to publish all the detected bounding boxes. How can I publish many bounding boxes?  The number of detections is not static, as I have no priori knowledge of how many detections the detector will produce. I have a tracker node which will then subscribe to the detector topic and perform tracking.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270649/how-can-i-publish-many-rois-in-a-detection-node?/) by [danaitri](https://answers.ros.org/users/31853/danaitri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Barring the use of any (proposed) [standard messages](https://discourse.ros.org/t/proposal-new-computer-vision-message-standards/1819) for vision, this could be done using lists/unbounded arrays of some simpler messages (such as [geometry_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry_msgs), perhaps four `Point32` per bbox, or `Polygon`s).

---

Edit: note that there are actually [people_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/people_msgs) that may be more appropriate for this, as they carry a bit more information than just bounding boxes. There are also quite some packages that implement either face or people tracking, such as [cob_people_detection](http://wiki.ros.org/cob_people_detection), [face_detector](http://wiki.ros.org/face_detector) and [face_recognition](http://wiki.ros.org/face_recognition). If nothing else, it might be good to take a look at how those packages publish their results and perhaps use a similar / the same method. `cob_people_detection` uses the [cob_people_detection_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/cob_people_detection_msgs) fi.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gvdhoorn  gave you very useful information and examples of similar message types which is interesting but having the same use case as yours I'm going with the following solution:

To acheive what you want, I think that you need to create and build your own message type, every detected face is sort of a ROI and the number of detections is rondom.

There is a predefined message type describing a ROI which is [sensor_msgs/RegionOfInterest](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/RegionOfInterest.html), so a message for a simple list of detected faces  `DetectedFaces.msg` can be defined as follows:

```
sensor_msgs/RegionOfInterest[]  detected_faces
```

But  it will be also useful to set an id or label for each detection and maybe a weigh or a score in order to pass all the intresting things to know about every single detection to your tracker or whatever subscriber to this message.

So I suggest creating two messages, one for a single detected face  description `DetectedFace.msg` and a second one which is a list of all the detections `DetectedFaceArray.msg` so their msg definitions can be done as follows:

```
std_msgs/Int32 label
sensor_msgs/RegionOfInterest detected_face
std_msgs/Float32 weigh
```

and

```
your_pkg_name/DetectedFace[] detected_faces
```

You can also add headers to these messages and any other information that you find useful.

See this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) for more details about the steps and configuration needed to create and build msg files. and make sure to add the `sensor_msgs` and `std_msgs` as `DEPENDENCIES` in your package definition.

Once your msgs are compiled try to create a simple publisher and subscriber to check them out.

*Good luck!*

---

Originally posted by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) with karma: 188 on 2017-10-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-23**:
Thanks for taking the time to write such an extensive answer.

I must note though: your suggestion (`label`, roi and `weigh[t]`) is essentially what the [cob_people_detection_msgs/html/PeopleDetection](http://docs.ros.org/electric/api/cob_people_detection_msgs/html/msg/PeopleDetection.html) msg ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-23**:
.. contains:

```
std_msgs/Header header
string label
string detector
float32 score
cob_people_detection_msgs/Mask mask
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped pose
```

(`mask` contains a `roi`).

My recommendation to @danaitri would still be to use some existing msg, instead of a custom one.

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2017-10-23**:
You are absolutely right, the cob_people_detection_msgs/PeopleDetection msg is very suitable for his need, I didn't see its content till now, so thanks for the info :) .